# How to get data from component in tab pane(s) after user fills in and clicks save on page - react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Working on a product and using `react-bootstrap`. To allow the user to enter in customer info. I'm using tabs so you have something like:

```
<Tab.Container id="CustTabs" defaultActiveKey="Details">
   ......
  <Tab.Content>
     <Tab.Pane eventKey="Details">
         <Details custInfo={this.state.custInfo} />
     </Tab.Pane>
     <Tab.Pane eventKey="Page2">
         <Page2 custInfo={this.state.custInfo} />
     </Tab.Pane>

    </Tab.Content>
</Tab.Container>
<Button onClick={this.SaveCust}>Save</Button>
```

So in `SaveCust()` I want to gather the data the user has input into the different panes and save it to the backend. What do I need to do to gather the data in each of those pages to push to the backend?
Of note: Each pane is a component in another source file allowing the user to enter in data. And I am using react-bootstrap.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use to define a parent component with the state like the shape of the data you want. Then create a method to handle this state and pass it in your page component and call it when your inputs change. Finally, the state has the data you want to post. Use it in your savecust method. Otherwise, check the library ecosytem ok react. There are a lot very helpful!

Comment: check the library ecosytem ok react? have an URL?

Comment: you can use formik

Answer (score 0):

The component that has the tabs should contain a state of all the values in the tabs then pass a function to the components that acts as the tabs eg in your case `Details` and `Page2`  inside the component invoke this function and it will propagate the changes back to the parent and update the specific fields there. So when you are ready to submit and call the `SaveCust` it will farword the content of the state to the backend. Something like this

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     //defind all the state variables that the tabs will use
   }
  }
 hangleTabValues =(object) => {
  //update the state values with the changed from tabs depending on which tabs you might defind different functions
 }
render(){
 return (
  <Tab.Container id="CustTabs" defaultActiveKey="Details">
   ......
  <Tab.Content>
     <Tab.Pane eventKey="Details">
         <Details hangleTabValues={this.hangleTabValues} custInfo={this.state.custInfo} />
     </Tab.Pane>
     <Tab.Pane eventKey="Page2">
         //this hangleTabValues={this.hangleTabValues} passed here might be different from the one above
         <Page2 hangleTabValues={this.hangleTabValues} custInfo={this.state.custInfo} />
     </Tab.Pane>

    </Tab.Content>
</Tab.Container>
//SaveCust will then access and submit the state values to the backend
<Button onClick={this.SaveCust}>Save</Button>
 )
}
```